# How to update existing columns in a dataframe based on multiple conditions on other columns in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, numpy

```
df1:

Pan_no   Target    Debt_aum  Hml
Xxx        0        5000     Low
YYY        1          0     medium 
ZZZ        0         200     Low
Aaa        1        15000    High
Yyy        1          0      High
```

Condition:

If the debt_aum =0 and target =1 then hml should be Low for those rows.

```
Expected Output:

Pan_no   Target   Debt_aum   Hml
Xxx        0        5000     Low
YYY        1          0      Low 
ZZZ        0         200     Low
Aaa        1        15000    High
Yyy        1          0      Low
```

In SQL I will just write an update statement. In python I am having trouble.
I tired doing

```
for i in df1['hml']:
   if df1[target] == 1 and df1[debt_aum] == 0:
      i = 'Low'
  else:
       i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `numpy.where` function:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df["Hml"] = np.where(((df["Debt_aum"] == 0) & (df["Target"])), "Low", df["Hml"])
df
```

##### Output

| Pan_no | Target | Debt_aum | Hml |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Xxx | 0 | 5000 | Low |
| YYY | 1 | 0 | Low |
| ZZZ | 0 | 200 | Low |
| Aaa | 1 | 15000 | High |
| Yyy | 1 | 0 | Low |

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df["Hml"] = df["Hml"].mask(df["Debt_aum"].eq(0)&df["Target"].eq(1),"Low")

>>> df
  Pan_no  Target  Debt_aum   Hml
0    Xxx       0      5000   Low
1    YYY       1         0   Low
2    ZZZ       0       200   Low
3    Aaa       1     15000  High
4    Yyy       1         0   Low
```

Comment: Thank you so much both the solutions worked

Comment: Happy to help. Just FYI, this is a `pandas` solution, no need to `import numpy`

Answer (score 0):

a solutiont with `loc`:

```
df1.loc[(df1['Debt_aum']==0)&(df1['Target'] == 1)] = 'Low'
df1
'''
  Pan_no Target Debt_aum   Hml
0    Xxx      0     5000   Low
1    Low    Low      Low   Low
2    ZZZ      0      200   Low
3    Aaa      1    15000  High
4    Low    Low      Low   Low
```